# inputfilestream to a String

Tags: java

I have the following logic to open a file:

Except what I want to do is not just print the file on the screen, but to take a line and store it to a String called test.

Can someone please help me with this ?

```
// fetch the file
String filename = "companySecret.txt";
String filepath = "C:\\";
String test;

java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(filepath + filename);

int i;

while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) 
{

    System.out.write(i);
}

fileInputStream.close();
```

Comment: Writing Java code in a JSP file instead of a Java class and having problems with *that* Java code doesn't make it a JSP problem. I removed the irrelevant JSP noise from the question. This is after all just basic Java. You'll also get better hits when you search using the "java" keyword instead of "jsp" keyword when having problems with Java, by the way. Only if you have problems with any JSP code **outside** `<% ... %>`, like `<some:taglib>` or `${someEl}`, then we can talk about a true JSP problem.

Comment: rename the variable `i` to `test` and you have it

Comment: @jalynn2 wrong. ``read()`` reads exactly one byte and returns an ``int`` representing that byte.

Comment: @f1sh +1 Tell him the truth. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) class and use the ReadLine method to extract the line from the file.

```
// fetch the file
String filename = "companySecret.txt";
String filepath = "C:\\";
String test;

java.io.FileReader fileInputReader = new java.io.FileReader(filepath + filename);
java.io.BufferedReader input = new java.io.BufferedReader( fileInputReader );


while ((test=input.readLine()) != null) 
{
    // Do something with the line...
}

fileInputStream.close();
```

Comment: Internal Servlet Error:

using StringBuilder I get the following error:org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSPNote: sun.tools.javac.Main has been deprecated.

Comment: @user2561610 that points to an entirely different problem with your development environment.

Comment: @Mr.Beer: I find readLine() difficult to use as it deletes the linebreaks. Of course you can insert these when concatenating the lines, but you have no knowledge which one (\n vs. \r\n) was used in the file.

Comment: @f1sh True, you don't know what was used in the file. But do you really need to? I usually use the `line.separator` JAVA property to re-inserting the line breaks if they are needed.

Comment: @Mr.Beer "Do you really need to" - Yes, you want the file's contents without any changes. And using your approach, you manipulate that content. Please note that ``line.separator`` contains the line break variant of the executing environment, which has nothing to do with the variant that the file contains. Save the file with windows and open it on a unix machine and you know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/):

```
String fileContents = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`

then

```
 StringBuilder test=new StringBuilder();
```

then in your while loop

```
  test.append("your String");
```

Or you can use `String` as you wish as follows

```
 String test=new String();

  test +=your_String;
```

Try this

```
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\Test.txt"));
   StringBuilder test=new StringBuilder();
   String str;
   while (sc.hasNext()){
       str=sc.next();
       System.out.println(str);
       test.append(str);
   }
```

To read specific line

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   public class Read {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   FileReader fr=new FileReader("D:\\Test.txt");
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
   StringBuilder test=new StringBuilder();
   String str;
   int count=1;
   while ((str=br.readLine())!=null){
       if(count==1){
           System.out.println(str);
           test.append(str);
       }
         count++;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: omg. this will A/ not compile. B/ if you make it so it does (by using append and by instanciating your string builder), it will show a list of integers representing the values of each byte of the file. totally undecipherable. (that's because read returns an int, not a byte or a char).

Comment: the second part of my comment still stands.

Comment: for some reason it doesnt like StringBuilder and i get the following error:

Comment: Internal Servlet Error:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSPNote: sun.tools.javac.Main has been deprecated.

Comment: hi hi all are here to minus.......but no one really want to edit my answer i just thought i was a String value. @ all keep in mind every one make mistakes

Comment: @Ruchira none of your edits contained any compiling code. You keep writing ``apend`` instead of ``append`` and at this point, none of your edits showed a solution to the problem.

Comment: @f1sh I just typed here not coded some where else. I guess you can understand what i mean. wait for my code :)

Comment: what if i wanted to read 1 particular line from a test file. For example line 32

Comment: The current revision of this answer uses a ``Scanner`` which splits the input at every whitespace. This something different than reading a file into a ``String``, as you get something totally different.

Comment: @f1sh I am only answering here for Op's query not yours. previously he just want to store text  as a String while printing'

Comment: Class reports.FileReader not found
Class reports.BufferedReader not found.

Comment: i'm assuming i have to use page import , but what class do i need to import

Comment: @user2561610 add imports as above

Comment: Now the issue I am having is I need to read the file from a windows network drive. Eg  //networkshare/e$/<filename>  not from the C:\\